# Why do I have to use the full path of Response.Cookies.Add(...) in a class that's not a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have a controller that can do the following:

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("cookietest",sessionToken);
```

As this is part of a login Action I am moving it from my Controller to my DataAction class.

In it, I am using System.Web.

Yet, i am unable to do the above and have to use the full path of:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("cookietest", sessionToken))
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

The controller has a property shortcut for Response. See [Spec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller(v=vs.118).aspx).

So in a controller class you can simply call `this.Response` however shorthand you drop the `this`.

Your `DataAction` does not specify a `Response` Property.

You could add the following code to you `DataAction` class to create such a property.

```
public HttpResponseBase Response
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//   Write cookie

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie");
        cookie.Value = "Hello..Its my world";

        this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    //Read Cookie

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        string cookie = "";
        if (this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("MyCookie"))
        {
            cookie = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["MyCookie"].Value;
        }
        ViewData["MyCookie"] = cookie;
        return View();
    }
```